Make Logitech Mouse side buttons visible to Windows
I have the exact same issue as stated here but I'm on Windows instead of Mac.
Logitech M650 L won't reveal the side buttons to the OS, I thought this happens because Logi Options + intercepts them before passing them forward to Windows.
However, even after uninstalling this app, the issue still remains.
Logitech M590 doesn't have this issue, this mouse is configured with the Logi Options app.
Even with that app installed, it passes the side buttons to the OS and all apps. I know this because various games have read these side buttons (as Mouse Button 4 and Mouse Button 5) when I try to customize keybinds with this mouse. And this just does not happen with M650 L.
Same is the case with AutoHotKey scripts. The scripts that utilize XButton1 and XButton2 (side buttons) all work fine with M590 and not at all with M650 L.
The referenced question mentions disabling input monitoring in "Security & Privacy" or disabling Logi Options in "System Preferences". I'm not sure what the Windows equivalent steps would be for these methods, if they do exist at all.
I couldn't find any setting that sounded like it would disable input monitoring in the Logi Options + app.

On a Windows PC, I found X-Mouse Button Control, https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm, more useful than Logitech's own utility (and a lot smaller!). It can translate mouse actions to a key press or other input AHK could interpret. [oops... that is not to be construed as a software recommendation, just a work-around.]
